# fish shell cannot find jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, fish

I'm just a beginner and try to use fish shell.

Command line cannot find jupyter notebook after I installed fish shell.

```
> jupyter notebook
fish: Unknown command 'jupyter'
```

jupyter is installed in pip3, and it originally in bash is working fine.

```
> pip3 show jupyter
Name: jupyter
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Jupyter metapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go.
Home-page: http://jupyter.org
Author: Jupyter Development Team
Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.org
License: BSD
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: ipywidgets, ipykernel, nbconvert, notebook, qtconsole, jupyter-console
```

Do I miss something path variable setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be customizing your $PATH in one of the bash config scripts such as ~/.bashrc. Possibly by sourcing a helper script to setup the environment for jupyter. Start bash and run `type jupyter` and `echo $PATH`. Then compare that to `echo $PATH` when running fish and add the missing directories. You'll want to make it permanent by adding `set PATH $PATH /missing/directory` to your ~/.config/fish/config.fish.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved after I adding my python3 bin path to fish config.

Comment: Not too intuituive answer. you need to make the answer simpler for people who are starting with new projects such as myself. I typed in `type jupyter echo $PATH` and it gave me `Could not find 'jupyter'`, which was my original problem

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add the line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to `anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command`.

For more information, see [this issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8222).